# Where is this going wrong? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, arrays, exception, bounds

I am trying to count the number of Space objects in a Space[][], of a particular colour. When I use this method to count the number of objects of a particular colour in a row, it works fine:

```
public int countRowWhite(Space[][] board, int row)//TESTED//when counting in a row, the columns         go up the row stays the
//same,THIS GOES THROUGH THE ROW ADDING UP NUMBERS OF WHITES
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int column=0; column<board.length;column++)
    {
        if((board[row][column]).getColour().equals(spaceColour.White))
        {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

However when I try this method, to count the number of objects in a column, I get an exception:

```
public int countColumnWhite(Space[][] board, int column)//when counting in a row, the columns go up the row stays the
//same,THIS GOES THROUGH THE ROW ADDING UP NUMBERS OF WHITES
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int row =0; column<board.length;row++)
    {
        if((board[row][column]).getColour().equals(spaceColour.White))
        {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I call both of these methods in the following test method:

```
public void testMethods()
   {
           Space[][] test = new Space[5][5];

   for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < test.length; j++){
              test[i][j] =  new Space(spaceColour.Null); 
         }
    }


   test[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
   test[0][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
   test[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
   test[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 

   System.out.println(countColumnWhite(test, 0));





   for(int row= 0; row<test.length;row++)
   {
       for(int column = 0; column<test.length;column++)
       {
           if (test[row][column].getColour().equals(spaceColour.White))
           {
               System.out.println("Whites at row: " + row + " and Column: "+ column);
           }
       }
   }
```

If it helps, the exception is always equal to the number of rows and columns the 2d array 'test' has

Comment: Are you sure that `countRowWhite` works as it should? It will work correct if your array have same number of row and columns, but in general case you should replace use `for(int column=0; column<board[row].length; column++)` instead of `for(int column=0; column<board.length; column++)`.

Comment: Always same number of rows and columns :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that this line:

```
for(int row =0; column<board.length;row++)
```

should be:

```
for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
```

Your terminating condition was checking that `column` is lesser than `board.length`, when it should be checking that `row` is lesser than `board.length`. You keep incrementing `row`, but the termination condition is never true, so you end up going outside the bounds of the array.

Another thing is that your code implicitly assumes that you are working with a square matrix (i.e 2-d array same number of rows and columns). So if you have unequal rows and columns, you will run into the same issue. If your assumption is valid, then this is fine. I imagine this is some kind of game board that is supposed to be square.

Comment: Thank you, I've been staring at this for ages with a blind eye

Comment: @user2969516 Happens to everyone :)

Comment: Additionally, both are checking against the same dimension, which works in the case of a square 2D array, but will fail if the number of rows and columns are not equal.

Comment: @DonRoby I was just writing that part when you commented!